# Cut functionality shortcut for folders and files

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm accustomed to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> combination to move files and folders using only the keyboard. Can I get the same functionality on OS X Lion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, but it's a little different in Lion.

In both the **move** and the **copy** situation, you use <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to put a file on the clipboard.

When pasting:

- To **copy** the file to the new location, press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
  [image]
- To **move** the file to the new location, press <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use <kbd>cmd</kbd> +<kbd>x</kbd> too : if I'm not mistaken, cut exists in Mac OS since the 10.4.8 version, it's just disable.

To get the combination <kbd>cmd</kbd> +<kbd>x</kbd> working, you could just enable it, by opening a terminal and run this command :

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AllowCutForItems 1
```

You could re-disable it, by changing the final "1" to "0".

**EDIT** :

I didn't try this trick for a while, so it appears that it's not working under Lion (It's was working on leopard for me).

Anyway jtbandes's solution is the best way to do cut and paste :)

Comment: The only problem is it doesn’t actually cut the files; it just copies them.